# python files - who to open corectly

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, math

We have file with some math problems like: 46 + 19 (only + or - and it built up this way: number, space, sign, space, number) and we need to transform it into a new file and solve them (46 + 19 = 65). We don't know how many exercises there will be or the number of digits in every number. Here is my code:

```
enter code here
input_file = open(r'C:\try\bla.txt', 'r')
nums = input_file.read()

y = 0
dig1 = ''
dig2 = ''
sign = ''
x1 = nums.find(' ')
x2 = x1 + 1

def one(dig1, dig2, y):
    for i in xrange(x1):
        dig1 += nums[y]
        y += 1

    for m in xrange(abs(-x2)):
        dig2 += nums[y + 1]
    y += 1

sign = nums[x2]

if sign == '+':
    sum = int(dig1) + int(dig2)

if sign == '-':
    sum = int(dig1) - int(dig2)

print dig1, dig2, '=', sum


for a in xrange(0):
    one(dig1, dig2, y)

one(dig1, dig2, y)
print 'f', nums[21]
#print dig1, dig2, '=', sum
```

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python read file", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: You'll need tutorials on reading from a file in general, and in splitting lines into their fields.

Comment: Can you explain bit more about: `We can't know how many exerxises or digits in evert number.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are want to get this(python3):

```
test.txt:
10 + 15
22 - 71
33 + 64
```

code:

```
import operator
op = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub}

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    args = i.split()
    val = op[args[1]](int(args[0]), int(args[-1]))
    r = f'{i.strip()} = {val}'
    print(r)
```

Comment: Please fix indent